# How to properly deal with errors on live django site?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a try and catch and there is an exception ... What is the proper way to deal with those exceptions/errors on a live production (django) site?

So I have

```
try:
    create_response = wepay.call('/account/create',
                                 {'name': name, 'description': desc})
    self.wepay_account_id = create_response['account_id']
    self.save()
except WePay.WePayError as e:
    ..... (what do I put here?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set up e-mail error reporting through Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

Or you can use a service like [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/) (has a free account) to track error occurances.

Or you could use self-hosted Greylog (like suggested in comments), here's a good guide for django: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/09/18/central-logging-django-graylog2-and-graypy/

Comment: There's also [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/), which is self-hosted. [An article by Tobias McNulty](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/09/18/central-logging-django-graylog2-and-graypy/) about integrating it with Django was published just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Respond with (optionally a redirect to) a appropriate page explaining the problem to the user and if possible, provide a solution. Serving a 500 to your users in production is something you want to avoid, so catching the exception is a good idea.

So:

```
except WePay.WePayError as e:
    return render_to_response('wepay_error_page.html')
```

or:

```
except WePay.WePayError as e:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/errors/wepay/')  # Note: better use urlresolvers
```

(note this particular code will only work if it's in a view)

Then (optionally), make sure you get a copy of the error, by for example sending yourself an email.

A suggestion for this particular case (if I interpret the code succesfully) may be to notify yourself, and repond with a page explaining to the user their payment went wrong. Tell them this might occur because of their actions (maybe they cancelled their payment), and provide contact details for when users think it was not their fault.

Django by default mails (when mail is properly configured) all 500 errors to settings.ADMINS, but these only occur on **uncaught** exceptions, so in this particular question services like Rollbar or a central logging solution will only work if you re-raise the exception (will result in a 500) or send the error to one of these manually in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the above solution of redirecting over to a page that explains WePay error, combined with using [django-wepay](https://github.com/lehins/django-wepay) app available on pypi that features logging of all errors, and optionally all calls.